# Reading String[] from JNA call fails

Tags: java, jna

I'm attempting to call following function via [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna):

> struct group * getgrnam (const char *name)

as described in:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Lookup-Group.html#Lookup-Group

According to the documentation the structure is following:

> char *gr_name
>
> The name of the group.
>
> gid_t gr_gid
>
> The group ID of the group.
>
> char **gr_mem
>
> A vector of pointers to the names of users in the group. Each user name is a null-terminated string, and the vector itself is terminated by a null pointer.

I created following simple test classes

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class Test {

    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
            CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)  Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"), CLibrary.class);

            void printf(String format, Object... args);

            public Group getgrnam(String groupName);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");

            Group group = CLibrary.INSTANCE.getgrnam(args[0]);

            System.out.println(group.gr_name);
            System.out.println(group.gr_mem);

        }
    }
```

and the Group class that represents the structure:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class Group extends Structure {
    public String gr_name;
    public int gr_gid;
    public String[] gr_mem = new String[128];

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add("gr_name");
        fields.add("gr_gid");
        fields.add("gr_mem");
        return fields;
    }
}
```

The [marshalling documentation of JNA](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/overview-summary.html#marshalling) states that char** is converted to String[].

However when I run this code I get following error:

> /tmp # java -cp .:jna-4.5.1.jar Test root Hello, World Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Reading array of
>   class java.lang.String from memory not supported
>       at com.sun.jna.Pointer.readArray(Pointer.java:538)
>       at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(Pointer.java:459)
>       at com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Structure.java:720)
>       at com.sun.jna.Structure.read(Structure.java:580)
>       at com.sun.jna.Structure.autoRead(Structure.java:2074)
>       at com.sun.jna.Structure.conditionalAutoRead(Structure.java:550)
>       at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:446)
>       at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:354)
>       at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getgrnam(Unknown Source)
>       at Test.main(Test.java:23)

How can the structure field of char** be properly converted?

Comment: The documentation I find merely states that `group` _"shall include"_ those 3 members, not that it will contain _only_ those members. So you may have to create a wrapper function in C that calls `getgrnam` and returns something that is more well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. This would also be a problem I guess. Looking at the source of JNL it looks like it is simply not implemented to convert char** located in a struct to a String[] in a object. I attempted 2-3 workarounds but no success so far. Will continue digging.

Comment: Can you just get an array of `Pointer`s and then use `getString()` on each `Pointer`?

Comment: @DanielWiddis tried that and it showed some progress. It works in a sense that the Pointer[] gets populated with some "data". Unfortunately attempting to read this data via getString() or even getChar() results in VM crash. Might be related to the first comment that the returned structure can contain more fields than documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self answering since I figured it out after some digging.

Major breakthrough was this tool: https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator

It generates Java classes from C structures which helps a lot!

In the end the Java class that correctly mapped the group structure was like this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * <i>native declaration : line 2</i><br>
 * This file was autogenerated by <a href="http://jnaerator.googlecode.com/">JNAerator</a>,<br>
 * a tool written by <a href="http://ochafik.com/">Olivier Chafik</a> that <a href="http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CreditsAndLicense">uses a few opensource projects.</a>.<br>
 * For help, please visit <a href="http://nativelibs4java.googlecode.com/">NativeLibs4Java</a> , <a href="http://rococoa.dev.java.net/">Rococoa</a>, or <a href="http://jna.dev.java.net/">JNA</a>.
 */
public class Group extends Structure {
  /**
   * Group name.<br>
   * C type : char*
   */
  public Pointer gr_name;
  /**
   * Password.<br>
   * C type : char*
   */
  public Pointer gr_passwd;
  /**
   * Group ID.<br>
   * C type : __gid_t
   */
  public int gr_gid;
  /**
   * Member list.<br>
   * C type : char**
   */
  public PointerByReference gr_mem;
  public Group() {
    super();
  }
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("gr_name", "gr_passwd", "gr_gid", "gr_mem");
  }
  /**
   * @param gr_name Group name.<br>
   * C type : char*<br>
   * @param gr_passwd Password.<br>
   * C type : char*<br>
   * @param gr_gid Group ID.<br>
   * C type : __gid_t<br>
   * @param gr_mem Member list.<br>
   * C type : char**
   */
  public Group(Pointer gr_name, Pointer gr_passwd, int gr_gid, PointerByReference gr_mem) {
    super();
    this.gr_name = gr_name;
    this.gr_passwd = gr_passwd;
    this.gr_gid = gr_gid;
    this.gr_mem = gr_mem;
  }
  public Group(Pointer peer) {
    super(peer);
  }
  protected ByReference newByReference() { return new ByReference(); }
  protected ByValue newByValue() { return new ByValue(); }
  protected Group newInstance() { return new Group(); }
//  public static Group[] newArray(int arrayLength) {
//    return Structure.newArray(Group.class, arrayLength);
//  }
  public static class ByReference extends Group implements Structure.ByReference {

  };
  public static class ByValue extends Group implements Structure.ByValue {

  };
}
```

The usage of PointerByReference for the gr_mem field (char** type in C) was the breakthrough.

Afterwards it can be read like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Group group = CLibrary.INSTANCE.getgrnam(args[0]);
    System.out.println(group.gr_name.getString(0));

    PointerByReference pbr = group.gr_mem;
    String[] groups = pbr.getPointer().getStringArray(0);

    for (String g : groups) {
      System.out.println(g);
    }
```